# Groovy + Java interface inheritance issue

Tags: java, groovy

If `B` implements `A` (Java classes), and `ABUtils` has a method:

```
public A getBar(String s)
{
    return new B(s);
}
```

what's wrong with the following code:

```
import A
import B

def foo = ABUtils.getBar("blah");
```

Why would it produce:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException:
    Cannot cast object 'blah' with class 'B' to class 'A'
```

Comment: looks ok to me... maybe B isn't declared to implement A? Just having the right methods isn't enough.

Comment: @injecteer, Yeah, it is.

Comment: @ammoQ: `B` implements `A`.

Comment: show some more code ;)

Comment: My best guess in that situation is that A in your groovy program means a different class A than the one referenced in ABUtils and B.

Comment: You must have a mistake in your project somewhere.  What you are describing will work with Java, Groovy, or a mix of Java and Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem at all.

A.java:

```
public interface A {}
```

B.java:

```
public class B implements A {}
```

ABUtil.groovy:

```
class ABUtils {
  A getBar() { new B() }
}

new ABUtils().bar.with {
  assert it instanceof A
  assert it instanceof B
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ javac *.java && groovy AB.groovy 
$
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my late reply! You were right and my problem was apparently of a classpath issue.